# What are real use cases multiple verilog wire drivers ?

Tags: verilog

Currently, learning Verilog. I found out there are few net types that can have multiple drivers and the value on the net will differ according to the type of net if `wire` or`wand` or `wor` or others.

I grab this, but why on earth anyone would use that ?? 
What are real life use cases ?

Also I feel like `wand` and maybe `wor` are not synthesizeble, am I right ?

Comment: Verilog is used for IC design, not just for FPGAs. There is a lot of parts of the language that are added to allow circuitry to be described.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you don't see this type of logic at the RTL level, but there are many technologies that use this at the device level, like [open collector circuits](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2012/basics-open-collector-outputs/), and [emitter coupled logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic). Also, these devices tend to consume more power, so they are only used where very high speed is required.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is not only used for FPGA design. It can also be used for ASIC design, or even for board-level design.

`wand` nets can be implemented with open-collector logic.

`wor` nets can be implemented with open-emitter logic (as in ECL designs).

Comment: I would say in reverse, "wand is a net language construction to represent properties of open-collector logic", not the other way around.